# Postfix only starts after "systemctl daemon-reload"

Tags: debian, email, postfix, systemd

Today I upgraded Postfix and everything was running fine until I decided to let the server reboot just to see if everything comes back up.

Everything went just fine but systemd seems to "ignore" the Postfix startup:

```
Oct  7 22:59:25 [REDACTED] systemd[1]: Stopped Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Oct  7 22:59:25 [REDACTED] systemd[1]: Stopping Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Oct  7 22:59:25 [REDACTED] systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Oct  7 22:59:25 [REDACTED] systemd[1]: Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
```

As you can see it shows *nothing about the Postfix startup* which is expected to be like this:

```
postfix: Postfix is running with backwards-compatible default settings
postfix: See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html for details
postfix: To disable backwards compatibility use "postconf compatibility_level=2" and "postfix reload"
postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system
```

When I type

```
service postfix start
```

the start process goes way too fast and looking into the process list with

```
ps -ef
```

doesn't list any Postfix services like pickup, tlsmgr, etc.

Now to fix this I found out that I simply have to reload systemd with

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

When using

```
service postfix start
```

systemd does it's job as it should be:

```
Oct  7 23:00:08 [REDACTED] systemd[1]: Reloading.
Oct  7 23:00:08 [REDACTED] systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 15min 23.517714s random time.
Oct  7 23:00:08 [REDACTED] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 3h 21min 57.996507s random time.


Oct  7 23:00:28 [REDACTED] systemd[1]: Created slice system-postfix.slice.
Oct  7 23:00:28 [REDACTED] systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)...
Oct  7 23:00:29 [REDACTED] postfix[1233]: Postfix is running with backwards-compatible default settings
Oct  7 23:00:29 [REDACTED] postfix[1233]: See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html for details
Oct  7 23:00:29 [REDACTED] postfix[1233]: To disable backwards compatibility use "postconf compatibility_level=2" and "postfix reload"
Oct  7 23:00:30 [REDACTED] postfix/postfix-script[1333]: starting the Postfix mail system
Oct  7 23:00:30 [REDACTED] postfix/master[1335]: daemon started -- version 3.1.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Oct  7 23:00:30 [REDACTED] systemd[1]: Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -).
```

When I reboot I have to reload systemd again in order to get Postfix working via the service command. This is a very strange behaviour and I haven't found any answers to this on the internet.

**System Specs:**

**CPU:** Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v3 @ 2.30GHz
**Memory:** 12 GB
**SSD:** 240 GB
**OS:** Debian 9 Stretch (64-bit)
All packages are up-to-date.
Virtualized with KVM.

*postfix.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=Postfix Mail Transport Agent
Conflicts=sendmail.service exim4.service
ConditionPathExists=/etc/postfix/main.cf

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*postfix@.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance %i)
Documentation=man:postfix(1)
PartOf=postfix.service
Before=postfix.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=postfix.service
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
GuessMainPID=no
ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/postfix/configure-instance.sh %i
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postmulti -i %i -p start
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postmulti -i %i -p stop
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/postmulti -i %i -p reload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have tried to fix this with

```
systemctl enable postfix.service
```

but that didn't work either.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:** Okay, this is very strange: The "networking" service fails to "raise the network interfaces". But when I run `ifconfig` the IPv4 and IPv6 interface are up and running correctly.

```
Okt 10 20:48:43 [REDACTED] ifup[423]: ifup: failed to bring up eth0
Okt 10 20:48:43 [REDACTED] systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Okt 10 20:48:43 [REDACTED] systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Okt 10 20:48:43 [REDACTED] systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Okt 10 20:48:43 [REDACTED] systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have touched my `interfaces` only once by assigning IPs to them 14 months ago.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your `postfix.service` file contents.  Also, search the `journalctl` output for mentions of `postfix`. Perhaps there is a note about why it didn't start at boot. Perhaps the network wasn't up when it tried to start at boot?

Comment: I looked into `/var/log/syslog` and it only says "Starting Postfix MTA" and that's it. Nothing else. Gonna post service unit files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, what finally helped me out was this simple command:

```
systemctl enable postfix@-
```

After rebooting everything starts up fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Seems to be a bug after upgrading from stretch 9.1 to stretch 9.2:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=877992

Did you try to reinstall postfix as described there? This didn't help on my system but maybe you do have more luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help me either. But it's good to hear that people are talking about it on Debian Bugtracking.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `postfix` only bind to certain IP addresses (the `inet_interfaces` option)? If so, there are a number of bugs that have been reported relating to startup failure - see [882141](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=882141) and [887992](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=877992) (as [mentioned](https://serverfault.com/a/877749/72404) by [Barit](https://serverfault.com/users/439036/barit)).

Comment: Yes, it binds to localhost, a IPv4 adress and a IPv6 adress but thankfully that was not the issue since it worked like that for a year. Although good to see that there are bugs in it which can explain some stuff.